# Rabbitmq and UI queue option called Move Messages

Tags: rabbitmq

I see if you click on a queue an option called Move Messages.  I am an administrator of rabbitmq.  However, users who have config, read, write to the queues do not see this option.

Does anybody know of a way to allow users to move messages with this option in the ui? They are not interested in shovel/shovel_management dynamic/static options.  They just want to use the ui if possible.

Additional info we just saw:
Apparently, if you disable shovel_management, the above ui option fails and says you need to enable shovel_management, so it is tied to shovel somehow.  Note that we have the user as a policymaker.  What is interesting is if you disable shovel and shovel_management the option does not go away.

Comment: I do not think that there is any way to get rid of the Move Messages section in the Management UI...

Comment: I am not trying to get rid of Move Messages.  I want to allow users to use it.  It is not clear how to get it so that users can see the option and use it.